# How to emulate windows laptop screen resolution and size to test frontend created on Macbook Retina screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive, screen, screen-resolution

I'm working on a web app frontend on a MacBook with Retina screen, but the app users primarily use windows laptops with 13/14" screens, and my frontend looks too big for them.

How can I accurately emulate windows laptops' screen size and pixel size/density to adjust my UI responsiveness?

I saw some online services where you can enter the link to preview it on different devices, but the app is on my localhost, which doesn't wok there. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

in google chrome open your app,

Press F12 to open dev tools

Now click on mobile emulator

[image]

then you can change the resolution from here and select responsive dimensions.

[image]